# Sharepoint timer job, method in Execute function doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint

I writening Timer Job for sharepoint 2010. But something is wrong.
When I debuging, watch doesn't show `int i` variable. I get an infformation:

> Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'i' as it is not available at
>   this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.

When debugger is on: `if (Directory.Exists(@"D:\File"))` debugger stop and doesn't check it. Program stop work in the same time.

My code:

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
        {

            int i = 0;

            if (Directory.Exists(@"D:\File"))
            {
                string[] filePath = filePath = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\File\");
            }
        }
```

When I make any changes I clean project and deploy it again.

Comment: Adding 'SOLVED' does not close the question as solved. Add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the SharePoint timer service

For SharePoint 2010:

```
net stop SPTimerV4
net start SPTimerV4
```